# Python reuse toolbar icon - not centered in button

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to duplicate the cursor buttons in a side panel.  the attached code gives most of the functionality but the icon is not centered on the button in the UI

[image: icon not ceneterd]

changing the x_scale does not help very much.  is there a way to center?  or a better way to code this?

The code:

````
import bpy
from bl_ui.space_toolsystem_common import ToolSelectPanelHelper

class CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Cursor Selection"
    bl_idname = "PT_CustomPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'New Tab'

    def draw(self, context):

        circle_icon_id = ToolSelectPanelHelper._icon_value_from_icon_handle('ops.generic.select_circle')

        layout = self.layout
        

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.alignment = 'CENTER'
        row.scale_x = 1.75
        row.scale_y = 1.75

        # Add the "Select Box" tool switch button to the panel

        row.operator("wm.set_tool_select_circle", text="", icon_value=circle_icon_id)



class WM_OT_SetToolSelectCircleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.set_tool_select_circle"
    bl_label = "Set Tool: Select Circle"
    bl_icon = "ops.generic.select_circle"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.select_circle")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_SetToolSelectCircleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_SetToolSelectCircleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````